# write a function that can retrieve only n period of data in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset, quantmod

Working with a set of sample data like below:

```
library(quantmod)

ticker<-"AAPL"
start_date <- as.Date("2020-01-01")
end_date <- as.Date("2021-01-01")
getSymbols("AAPL", from=start_date, to=end_date)

data<-AAPL$AAPL.Adjusted
```

Say if I only need the last 10 or 20 columns and put into a subset, instead of using below line:

```
n=10

new_data<-tail(data,n=n)
    
 > new_data
           AAPL.Adjusted
2021-01-15      125.2671
2021-01-19      125.9469
2021-01-20      130.0850
2021-01-21      134.8537
2021-01-22      137.0213
2021-01-25      140.8146
2021-01-26      141.0511
2021-01-27      139.9673
2021-01-28      135.0705
2021-01-29      130.0161
```

Is there a better way to retrieve data from the data set containing "n" period only? Thanks.

Comment: `subset(data, seq(nrow(data))>=nrow(data) - 10 + 1)` but why not just use `tail(data, n)`??

Comment: @Onyambu I think they want to subset before it is downloaded into R.

Comment: Why not just set `from` to `to - n days` ?

Comment: in what ways are you wanting the new method to be "better"? Because `tail()` seems ideal

Comment: @onyambu, that's exactly what I want , sorry my post is not very clear. I was also thinking, if I can add a filter like x=today-1, data collecting from x-n , so say if n=10, the data downloaded will be showing date x-1 to x-11. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function Bubbles is looking for is this:

```
previous_n_days<- function(d, n){
    d %>% tail(n) %>%
    head(n-1)
    }
# this assumes data goes right up until today
```

Or, if `subset()` is required, this:

```
previous_n_days <- function(d, n){
    # check if it's in the last n days using subset
    subset(d, between(index(d), Sys.Date() - n - 1, Sys.Date() -1))
}
```

Comment: This is basically tail(x, n). I'm not sure why OP wants a different approach.

Comment: I have no clue @Harshvardhan 